# MySQL error showing while creating table to make a relation with another by using foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have onetables empadd. Now i want to create an another table named  leave that connects empadd to make a relation. But while doing this i get the below error,

code
create table leave(LeaveId int not null auto_increment,LeaveType varchar(255),Department varchar(255),FromDate varchar(255),ToDate varchar(255),Days int,Reason varchar(255),primary key(LeaveId),foreign key(EmployeeId) references empadd(EmployeeId));

Error

Comment: Error showing :-   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leave(LeaveId int not null auto_increment,LeaveType varchar(255),Department varc' at line 1

Comment: You're better off editing your question to include that error message, instead of hiding it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), `leave` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.  You can use it if you put quotes around it, but you might want to consider changing the name of the table to something not reserved.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But it doesn't seems that there is no table named leave in db!